# How to change Netbeans cache directory?

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way to change Netbeans (7.0.1) cache directory?

I'm just wonna change directories of cache/temp for few apps... and one of them is NetBeans...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is not possible for Netbeans 7 (unless you relocate the whole userdir or create links as suggested by @MadWizard).

Fortunately, it seems this **will** be possible in Netbeans 7.1 by using the new `--cachedir` command-line option: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir

Answer (score 1):

Quoting http://platform.netbeans.org/articles/installation.html

> It is not reasonable to share this directory between different Products - the cache would be useless, the logs would get confusing and also the user modifications to the config would could be ambiguous. That is why each Product shall define its own directory prefix (based on its name) and pass it into the general nbexec command (for example using the --defaultuserdir parameter). The user can override the default during invocation of the the product launcher (e.g. nbweb --userdir myuserdir).

Review documentation pointed by me. If it does not help, you may consider using links, ie. create cache dir where desired and then within netbeans directory structure (described by the page) create link pointing to prepared cache.