# Which Netbeans Set-up and Configuration is in-use?

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration, settings

I am getting trouble with NetBeans *supervision* of my project-s.  On one project, it tells me ALL the classes are: "Duplicate Class"-s.

According to this question:

- [How to change Netbeans cache directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034660/netbeans-cache-dir)

We can't expect to set a specific Netbeans folder.  I'm not too concerned about why.  I want a method to coerce Netbeans to use a single cache that I specify.  For instance, a short look to day found TWO netbeans folders on Windows.

- c:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\NetBeans\8.0
- C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0

for the same user (*me*).  A folder compare shows that the two are Different.  So there's every opportunity to get stuff mixed-up, confused or spurious errors.

Does anyone have either information on how to better manage our netbeans set-ups, documentation on the info maintained in netbeans folders and/or tools to help with stuff?

It is a major pain to have a small but critical project just blow-up at the end of the week just from a tooling issue.  Helpful tips are most welcome, and my *thanks in advance*.

Comment: I'd start with deleting `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\var`, but you could try moving `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0` to a temp location and see what you get...

Comment: Yes, I did that.  I can fix these problems with a hack like today.  I'm really looking for something long-term that means I can keep working, not interrupt things when this happens.  It always happens when there's a deadline or something ;-)  For now.  Renaming the Cache folder was sufficient to solve this problem.